# Query all posts which do not have tags assigned to them

Tags: tags, query

Is there a way to query posts which **do not** have tags assigned to them?

```
query_posts('tag='tag_exmaple'&posts_per_page=-1');
```

Ty very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use the `tag_not_in` parameter if you have the tag id and if not then you can use `tax_query` parameter like so:

```
$tag_to_exclude = 'example_tag';
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($tag_to_exclude),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        )
);
query_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get an array of all of the tag ids and send it to the "tag__not_in" parameter. Not the most elegant solution, but I'm not sure how else it would be accomplished.